# combine same column from various data frames into new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, cbind

I have several dataframes that look like this:

```
df1
Time Terrain 
1     Land
2     Land 
3     Land  
4     Land
```

I want to take the column "Terrain" from each dataframe and put them all in a new one, giving the columns of the new dataframe the name of which dataframe it was extracted from. Should look like this:

```
combined_terrain

df1  df2  df3
Land Land Sea
Land Sea  Air
Land Sea  Land
Land Sea  Land
```

I know I have to use `cbind` but I have several dataframes and don't want to be typing each out. Do I loop it by making a list of the different dataframes?

Comment: `cbind()` and then change `colname()`'s.

Comment: thanks @mtoto, but I didn't want to write each dataframe out.

Comment: @Bonono I posted a solution below.  Can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place all the datasets (assuming that it starts with 'df' followed by numbers) in a `list` ('lst').  Then  use `lapply` to extract the 'Terrain' and `cbind` it

```
setNames(do.call(cbind, lapply(lst, `[`, 'Terrain')), nm1)
```

#### data

```
nm1 <- ls(pattern="df\\d+")
lst <- mget(nm1)
```